# git unable to commit - error husky > npm run -s commitmsg

Tags: node.js, git

I just cloned a project from GitHub and trying to commit changes locally

```
$ git commit -m 'readme updated'
```

its showing error

```
husky > npm run -s commitmsg (node v7.10.0)
```

[image]

even when I tried to commit with vs-code source controller - same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, there's a git hook validating the commit messages. They're required to have the specified format (`<type>(<scope>): subject`).

On https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#commit examples are given: `docs(changelog): update change log to beta.5`.
In your case, it would be something like `docs: update readme` or `docs(readme): Do stuff`.

If you want to contribute to angular, you should stick to this format. If you want to, say, test around for yourself, you might do as suggested: `git commit --no-verify`.

Comment: it works `git commit -m  'docs: update readme'`  ,  `git commit -m  'fix(animation): update readme'`    Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

As specified by the error message, your commit message needs to follow the format `<type>(<scope>): subject`

Answer (score 1):

For this error I am using

```
git commit --no-verify -m "your commit message"
```